# DomXPath: Search inside DomXPath query result?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, xpathquery

How can I query an xpath result for a sub element, without querying the entire document again?

I query my document to find the last `<li>` with the class `menu-item`:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML( $html );
// $html is invalid (and should be at this point),
// so use @ sign to suppress errors
$xpath = new DomXPath( $doc );
$li = $xpath->query( "(//li[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'menu-item')])[last()]" )->item( 0 );
```

The above works just fine, now I want to query `$li` to find the following:

```
$p = $xpath->query( "//p[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'field-description')]" )->item( 0 );
```

A `p` tag with class `field-description`. This does not work and returns the first instance found, if I modify it and use the `[last()]` (whatever this is) then it works, but it's not necessarily the optimal solution here:

```
$p = $xpath->query( "(//p[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'field-description')])[last()]" )->item( 0 );
```

The above line works, but I want to query inside `$li` not the entire document again.

Answer (score 4):

[The second argument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) to `query` is the `contextnode`, which limits the search to within that node. However, if you use an absolute xpath, `query` will still return nodes for the entire document.

```
php > $dd = new DomDocument();
php > // deliberately using malformed html.
php > $dd->loadhtml('<html><head><title>wat</title></head><body><div>Hello, <p>world</p></div><div class="container"><p>I like pie</div></body></html>');
php > $xp = new DomXPath($dd); 
php > $container = $xp->query('//div[@class="container"]')->item(0);
php > var_dump($xp->query('//p'));
class DOMNodeList#6 (1) {
  public $length =>
  int(2)
}
php > var_dump($xp->query('//p', $container));
class DOMNodeList#4 (1) {
  public $length =>
  int(2)
}
php > var_dump($xp->query('p', $container));
class DOMNodeList#5 (1) {
  public $length =>
  int(1)
}
```

You can use a pattern like `.//x` to match all `x` elements recursively within a context node. (HT: [Alf Eaton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145899/alf-eaton))

Comment: What about when `p` is not a direct child of `.container` in your example. For example, in my html my `p` tag is located in: `div.menu-item-settings` and then in `p.field-description`. My results for searching for `$xpath->query( 'p', $li );` in my example still return 0 results, how can I find `p` within `$li` without knowing the full path within `li`?

Comment: `$xp->query('.//p', $container)`